# How to parse out specific filenames from basename in bash

Tags: bash

I'm working on the following script for a research project with my school

```
for f in $(ls Illumina_Data/Aphyllon/PE150_2016_04_05* ); do
    if [[ "${f}" == *"_R1"* ]] ;then
            echo "INITIALIZE THE SEQUENCE"
            echo `basename " ${f%%_R1*}"`
            get_organelle_from_reads.py -1 ${f%%_R1*}_R1_001.fastq.gz \
              -2 ${f%%_R1*}_R2_001.fastq.gz \
              -o Sequenced_Aphyllon_Data/`basename "${f%%_R1*}"` \
              -R 15 -k 21,45,65,85,105 -F embplant_pt
    fi
done
```

What we're getting with this script right now is kinda of a long name and we're wanting it to be shorter for organization sake. If you take a look at the -o command and the section that says `Sequenced_Aphyllon_Data/'basename "${f%%_R1*}"'`. What this is spitting out is the entire fastq file name that we originally used of the following format

```
A_speciesname_IDtag_(some set of number and letters)_(some set of numbers and letters)_(some set of number and letters)_(some set  of numbers and letters)
```

The issue I'm having is that we're wanting the `A_speciesname_IDtag` section to remain, though sometimes our reads don't contain the IDtag section which makes it so we need to parse at either the second or third `_` from the left. However there are always four `_` from the right without fail.

So is there a way to specifically target an `_` from the right of a string? From the right the amount of `_` separating what we need will always remain the same but will change from the left.

Comment: read this https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I would always prefer using `find` and a `while` loop instead of this. To be save with filenames containing spaces. Besides this use bash-regex in the `if` clause.

Comment: How do you determine how much of the filename you want to keep? When you mention the number of `_` to keep, what is that decision based on?

Comment: What about `for f in Illumina_Data/Aphyllon/PE150_2016_04_05*_R1*` ?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` with a lookahead assertion?

```sh
$ s1=dog_ID1_a000_b111_c222_d333
$ s2=cat_a000_b111_c222_d333
$ grep -oP ".+(?=_\w+_\w+_\w+_\w+)" <<<$s1
dog_ID1
$ grep -oP ".+(?=_\w+_\w+_\w+_\w+)" <<<$s2
cat
```